# VBA - Adding only certain rows into an array and then printing those values

Tags: excel, vba

Im learning some VBA to achieve a task i have so i may be asking multiple questions as i go, but first.

If i have a datasheet with rows and columns, some rows have SA and some rows have SI in column B, i want the data from 7 or 9 dependant on the value in column B and 11 irrespective.

What i have currently is as follows.

```
Dim SA, SI
            SA = Evaluate("=IF(2="SA"), 9, 11")
            SI = Evaluate("=IF(2="SI"), 7, 11")
End Sub
```

Im getting an error about syntax when i do this.

To ensure the correct data is being copied im also trying to print those respective arrays to other sheets.

```
Sub PrintTest()
    Dim SA() As Variant
    Dim SI() As Variant
    ReDim SA(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
    PrintArray SA, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").[A1]
End Sub
```

This is all under a button and looks like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SA, SI, R&, C%
            SA = Evaluate("=IF(2="SA"), 9, 11")
            SI = Evaluate("=IF(2="SI"), 7, 11")
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Dim SA() As Variant
    Dim SI() As Variant
    ReDim SA(1 To 3, 1 To 3) ' make it flexible
    PrintArray SA, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").[A1]
End Sub
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are adding this variable in you need to add it to the evaluate string

```
SA = Evaluate("=IF(2="SA"), 9, 11")
```

needs to be

```
SA = Evaluate("=IF(2="+SA+"), 9, 11")
```

Comment: Ah i see, my mistake!

I went with a different method in the end.

   Dim Ary As Variant
   Dim Sa() As Variant, Si() As Variant
   Dim r As Long, i As Long, j As Long
   Ary = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   i = 1: j = 1
   For r = 1 To UBound(Ary)
      If Ary(r, 2) = "SA" Then
         ReDim Preserve Sa(1 To 2, 1 To i)
         Sa(1, i) = Ary(r, 9)
         Sa(2, i) = Ary(r, 11)
         i = i + 1
      ElseIf Ary(r, 2) = "SI" Then
         ReDim Preserve Si(1 To 2, 1 To j)
         Si(1, j) = Ary(r, 7)
         Si(2, j) = Ary(r, 11)
         j = j + 1
      End If
   Next r